# Create intellisense from list of string

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to create intellisense from a dynamic list of string?
For example

```
Dim fruit as List (Of String) = New List (Of String)
fruit.AddRange({"Apple","Orange","Water Melon","Grape","Banana"})
```

Then when I type "fruit." those list will show up, probably will like below

[image]

Comment: [How to: Declare Enumerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxssy3ak.aspx)